# lictpicker value is lost in wp8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listpicker

In my windows phone 8 application I am using `listpicker` that have two values `Dark` and `Light`, when I select `Light` from `listpicker` and restart my application, `listpicker` value i.e `Light` is lost and it holds default value i.e `Dark`.

And below is `listpicker` selectionChanged method:

```
private void themelistPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string themename = string.Empty;
            IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
            ListPickerItem lpi = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
            themename = lpi.Content.ToString();
            value = lpi.Content.ToString();
            if (themename == "Dark")
            {
                if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
                {
                    settings.Add("userData", themename);
                }
                else
                {
                    settings["userData"] = themename;
                }
                settings.Save(); 
            }
            else
            {

                if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
                {
                    settings.Add("userData", themename);
                }
                else
                {
                    settings["userData"] = themename;
                }
                settings.Save();
            }
        }
```

What can I do, Kindly suggest me.
Waiting for reply.

Thanks

Comment: did the answer work or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

XAML:

```
        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="themelistPicker1" SelectionChanged="themelistPicker1_SelectionChanged">
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Light"></toolkit:ListPickerItem>
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="Dark"></toolkit:ListPickerItem>
        </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

CS:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    if (settings.Contains("userData"))
    {
        string str = settings["userData"].ToString();
        if (str == "Dark")
            themelistPicker1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        else
            themelistPicker1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
private void themelistPicker1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (themelistPicker1 != null && themelistPicker1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        ListPickerItem lpi = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem as ListPickerItem;
        string themename = lpi.Content.ToString();
        if (!settings.Contains("userData"))
            settings.Add("userData", themename);
        else
            settings["userData"] = themename;
        settings.Save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving selected value from ListPicker not the state of control. Add code to your `Loaded` or `NavigateTo` events of page that contains `ListPicker` and if Light is present in IsolatedStorageSettings, then programatically change selected index...

If you store this kind of settings in IsolatedStorage, you can just add/remove key without checking value to simplify it. So when the user selects Light, you add some key to storage, when dark you delete it. Key presence then mean that Light is selected :)